# AngularJS - Disable select list option if expression is true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-directive

I've tried to disable a materializeCSS select list option is a particular expression is true, but this doesn't seem to be working using the method below:

```
<option data-ng-disabled="employeeIsMale" value="maternity">Maternity</option>
```

I've defined the truth value of this expression like below on load, which is obviously working, because the correct message is logged to the console:

```
$document.ready(function() {
    if ($scope.employee.gender === 'Male') {
        $scope.employeeIsMale == true;
        console.log("Employee is Male");
    } else {
        $scope.employeeIsMale == false;
        console.log("Employee is Female");
    }
})
```

How can I use the expression like this to disable the select option?

Full HTML:

```
<select data-ng-change="showAbsenceInputs()" data-ng-model="absenceTypes" id="absenceTypeSelect" name="absenceTypeSelect" material-select watch class="validate" required>

  <option value="" selected>Select an option</option>

  <option data-ng-disabled="employeeIsMale" value="maternity">Maternity</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use assignment operator `=`.You are using comparison operator for assignment.

```
 $scope.employeeIsMale = true;
```